# Loading Local Images in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js, replit

I'm currently working on a p5.js project hosted on Replit, and I could use some assistance with loading local images into my sketch. Despite meticulously organizing the images within my Replit project directory, I've encountered a frustrating issue where they simply won't load.

The error message I'm receiving reads: "p5.js says: It looks like there was a problem loading your image. Try checking if the file path is correct, hosting the file online, or running a local server."

Now, I've double-checked the file paths and ensured the images are in the correct location within my Replit project. However, I'm still unable to load the images successfully.

Given that I'm using Replit to host my project, I'm wondering if there's a specific approach or workaround I should be considering for loading local images in a p5.js sketch on Replit.

If anyone has experience with this or knows how to effectively load local images in a p5.js sketch hosted on Replit, your insights would be incredibly valuable to me.

I attempted to load local images into my p5.js sketch on Replit by ensuring correct file paths and organization within the project directory. I expected the images to load successfully into the sketch. However, despite my efforts, I consistently encountered an error message stating: "p5.js says: It looks like there was a problem loading your image."

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of your code. Is repl.it exposing those files to the public web via some URL or server, as the error message suggests? If not, that's probably why they won't load.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.